# LTE通信でHTTPにてLINEへ通知時に稀にエラーになってフリーズする

Tags: spresense, arduino

デジタルピン入力の状態（ON/OFF）を定期的にLINE通知したいのですが、数百回に一回程度の確率で稀にエラーになってフリーズし、その後動作しなくなってしまいます。
対策を教えてください。

#### 開発環境等

・spresense本体＋spresense lte拡張ボード
・Arduino IDE

#### コード（一部）

```c
void send(String message) {
  const char* host = "notify-api.line.me";
  const char* token = "XXX";

  LTETLSClient tlsClient;
  // SDカードから証明書ファイルを読み込む
  File rootCertsFile = theSD.open(ROOTCA_FILE, FILE_READ);
  tlsClient.setCACert(rootCertsFile, rootCertsFile.available());
  rootCertsFile.close();  
  HttpClient client = HttpClient(tlsClient, server, port);

  LTE lteAccess;

  // LTE接続開始
  while (true) {
    if (lteAccess.begin() == LTE_SEARCHING) {
      if (lteAccess.attach(LTE_APN, LTE_USER_NAME, LTE_PASSWORD) == LTE_READY) {
        Serial.println("attach succeeded.");
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("An error occurred, shutdown and try again.");
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
    }
  }  

  //LineのAPIサーバに接続
  if (!client.connect(host, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    client.stop();
    lteAccess.shutdown();
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");
  //リクエストを送信
  String query = String("message=") + message;
  String request = String("") +
               "POST /api/notify HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Authorization: Bearer " + token + "\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: " + String(query.length()) +  "\r\n" + 
               "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n" +
                query + "\r\n";

  client.print(request);

  //受信終了まで待つ 
  while (client.connected()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(line);
    if (line == "\r") {
      break;
    }
  }

  String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');

  Serial.println(line);

  client.stop();
  lteAccess.shutdown();

}
```

#### 実行時のシリアルコンソール表示

上記コードの

```
String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
Serial.println(line);
```

個所にて

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 18:36:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:altcom/gw/apicmdgw.c line: 381 task: apicmdgw_main
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d04f26c
up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d035a00
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
up_dumpstate:   used: 000000f0
up_dumpstate: User stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d04f2f0
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000fd4
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000238
up_stackdump: 0d04f260: 00000003 0d034d94 00000001 00000003 00000000 0d0101a9 00000000 000007d6
up_stackdump: 0d04f280: 000007d8 0d048260 000007e8 0d01036b 00000010 000007d8 00000001 0d048260
up_stackdump: 0d04f2a0: 0d036d28 c5baedfe 0d0471c0 0d04b280 0d010201 0d0471c0 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d04f2c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d01051b 00000002 0d04f316 00000101 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d04f2e0: 00000000 0d003b4f 00000000 00000000 deadbeef 0d04f300 0d04f30e 00000000
up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=0 of 0
up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=584 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=3 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=4 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: init: PID=5 Stack Used=1448 of 8172
up_taskdump: cxd56_pm_task: PID=6 Stack Used=320 of 996
up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=7 Stack Used=320 of 1020
up_taskdump: thrdpool_no841: PID=2804 Stack Used=396 of 2004
up_taskdump: thrdpool_no842: PID=2805 Stack Used=496 of 980
up_taskdump: altmdm_pm_task: PID=2806 Stack Used=432 of 996
up_taskdump: altmdm_xfer_task: PID=2807 Stack Used=568 of 1500
up_taskdump: apicmdgw_main: PID=2808 Stack Used=648 of 4052
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTE のライブラリの、アサーションを出している場所が、github 上の最新ソースと行番号が違うのでよくわかりませんでした。

最新バージョンにしたら、解決したりしませんかね。

spresense　のサポート体制がわからないけど、
お使いの　LTEの、ライブラリーは、安定したいわゆる枯れているライブラリーですか？
オープンソースの、ライブラリーならば、
開発元にバグ報告したら喜ばれるかもしれません。

### 追記

その後、ちょっとソースを眺めてみましたが

`sdk/modules/lte/altcom/include/gw/apicmdgw.h`
の
`APICMDGW_SEND_ONLY`
マクロがあやしいのでは？
私のところでは実際の環境がないので何とも言えないのですが、

```
#define APICMDGW_SEND_ONLY(cmd) \
  (apicmdgw_send(cmd, NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
```

となっていますが 最後の 引数 `0` は 本当は `SYS_TIMEO_FEVR` (-1)
が正しいのではないのでしょうか？
他では `SYS_TIMEO_FEVR` を使っているのに ここだけ `0` なのは
違和感があります。

行番号がずれている件ですが、最新バージョンでは この部分は アサーションから
ログ出力に変わってますね・・。
最新にすれば、問題は出なくなるのかもしれませんが、根本的な解決ではないのかも。

もし、ソースからビルドして動作確認できるようでしたら、修正して試してみては
いかがでしょうか？

それで、うまくいくようなら github に pull リクエストを出すとか・・。

環境が整っているなら、試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます、とりあえず最新バージョンにして再度試してみます。Spresenseの問合せ先はstackoverflowなので、こちらに質問しています。通信関連のライブラリは、安定しているもの私にはわかりませんがこちらを利用しています。#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <LTE.h>

Comment: 最新化して試しましたが、元々質問に記載のエラーは出なくなりましたが、他のエラーが出たり、これまで動作していた関係なさそうな個所が動かなくなったりときりがなくなってしまいました。まだ新しい物なので仕方がないです。調べ方学ばせて頂きました、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

根本原因解決にはならないので、あくまでもフリーズから抜ける方法になりますが、Watchdogというライブラリが使えると思います。
[SPRESENSE Watchdogライブラリ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_watchdog_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA)

このライブラリを使うことで `send()` 関数が15秒以上返らなかった場合、強制的にリセットすることができます。

```
// Watchdogを初期化
Watchdog.begin();
// Watchdogタイマーを15000msecで開始
Watchdog.start(15000);

send();

// Watchdogタイマーを終了
Watchdog.stop();
// Watchdogをファイナライズ
Watchdog.end();
```

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: client.post方式にして、ご回答の方法で実装しようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 最近ファームウェアのアップデートがあったようで、これを使ったらフリーズ問題が解決するかもしれません。アップデートを試みてもよいかもしれません。[SDK Ver2.3.0 Example lte_awsiotを長時間実行したら、エラーとリセットが発生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82861/sdk-ver2-3-0-example-lte-awsiot%e3%82%92%e9%95%b7%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%82%bb%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)　そして、最近のSDK(私はSDK2.3.1を使いました。)でエラーが減ったような気がします。